# GradientDrawable setColors for older API levels

Tags: android

Is it possible to set the colors array of a gradient in a shape on a lower API level than API 16 (JellyBean)?

I'm currently using:

```
GradientDrawable gd = (GradientDrawable)this.getBackground();
int[] colors = {0xFFFF0000, 0xFFCC0099};
gd.setColors(colors);
```

Which works great, but I am hoping to support API Level 8 (Froyo) or 10 (Gingerbread v2).

Answer (score 6):

<s>I don't think there is an easy way of doing this, so here's what I'd suggest: Create a new [`GradientDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html) based on the parameters of the old one (for APIs below 16).</s> Thanks to [@StephenNiedzielski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/970346/stephen-niedzielski) for pointing out the flaw here—`getOrientation()` is not available below API 16.

There is no way to do this without Reflection, as you need the orientation of the drawable in order to create it anew. If you already *have* the orientation, you can do this:

```
GradientDrawable gd = (GradientDrawable) getBackground();
int[] colors = {0xFFFF0000, 0xFFCC0099};
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
    gd = gd.mutate(); // For safe resource handling
    gd.setColors(colors);
} else {
    // Fallback for APIs under 16.
    GradientDrawable ngd = new GradientDrawable(/* Orientation variable */, colors);
    // You may have to set other qualities of `ngd` here to make it match.
    setBackgroundDrawable(ngd);
}
```

So, without that information, you'd have to use Reflection on APIs below 16. While it's hacky, it's reasonably safe since the implementations of those APIs *shouldn't* ever change (since they're no longer being updated).

If it suits your fancy, you can use [Reflection to access the `GradientState` inner class](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/private-fields-and-methods.html). Basically, you would need to emulate the call `gd.mGradientState.mOrientation` (as mentioned in the comments) that the `getOrientation()` method performs. As both of those are private, you'd have to [use Reflection](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/private-fields-and-methods.html).

Comment: Oops. I forgot to `mutate()`! But that really sucks. I need the rest of the shape in order for this to work. I guess I'll have to create the shape in Java. Am I able to reference the shape with an Id and mutate its properties, or will I just have to create on from scratch every time?

Comment: I think you may have to recreate it, since `mutate()` doesn't create a new object, only reinitializes it. What I would probably do is create a class like `GradientDrawableState`, with the values you need to retain, then create a new `GradientDrawable` from that custom state each time. It seems ugly and unnecessary, I know, but it may be your best shot. Reflection is other option.

Comment: It sounds like thats the only way to do it, though. How did you know that `GradientDrawableState` will encapsulate the entire `Shape` object?

Comment: Oh, I wasn't comparing it to the actual object's state (which is `GradientDrawable.GradientState`, and which does also track the state), just that you'd want a custom class to keep track of all the information for you.

Comment: Sorry for the massive delay, but how would I be able to apply the entire `Shape` object to the `View`s background? Given that the `GradientDrawable` is essentially the `<gradient/>` component, what could I use to represent the `Shape` object in Java?

Comment: As misleading as it is, the `GradientDrawable` represents the entire shape (see [compiled resource type](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape)). It has methods like [`setCornerRadii()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html#setCornerRadii(float[])) that help you set the other details of the shape.

Comment: Oh. Thats perfect, then. I don't know how I missed that. Thanks again!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22542/discussion-between-rileye-and-eric)

Comment: `getOrientation()` requires API 16 or above.

Comment: @StephenNiedzielski You're absolutely right, I have to wonder why anyone ever upvoted this. Seems the only way would be through reflection (calling `gd.mGradientState.mOrientation`). I'll update my answer when I get a minute.