# Have I to create SweepGradient object every time when I need to change its colors positions?

Tags: android

I'm doing circle animation with change of positions of colors in a SweepGradient and after creation of the shader I set a local matrix for it to rotate gradient.

**So my question is:**

Can I reuse my created SweepGradient object to change colors positions in it or I have to create it every time when I have a new state.

**Second one:**

And if I have to create it every single time then I suppose I must set a local matrix every single shader as well. Must I?

Comment: you have to create it every time if you are using xml drawable but I guess if you use `GradientDrawable` then you might be able to change the color in runtime, give it a try.

Comment: @hfarhanahmed, to set offsets of colors programmatically it's required API level 29(

Comment: and that's doesn't suit me

Comment: No you can create a `GradientDrawable` for APIs prior to 29. Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115715/how-do-i-programmatically-set-the-background-color-gradient-on-a-custom-title-ba

Comment: @hfarhanahmed, I do create GradientDrawable but as I said the method [setColors()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html#setColors(int%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D)) required API level 29

Comment: and the method is the only way how to set colors positions as it seems

Comment: Can't you create a new instance of `GradientDrawable` whenever you want to change the color?

Comment: @hfarhanahmed, then I don't see any constructor which would take colors offsets

Comment: `GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable(
        GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[] {Colors.parseColor("#FFFFFF"),Colors.parseColor("#000000")});`

Comment: @hfarhanahmed, but there are only orientation and colors here. It doesn't accept offsets like the method setColors(colors, offsets) do

Comment: No, you can't set the offset, this is the best way to handle it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246499/gradientdrawable-setcolors-for-older-api-levels

Comment: @hfarhanahmed, but there's no info about colors offsets in there

Comment: @hfarhanahmed, can I use reflection if I have API level less than required?

Comment: @hfarhanahmed otherwise what do you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207397/discussion-between-hfarhanahmed-and-algernone).